# can not upload more than 10 files using AFNetworking

Tags: php, iphone, ios, afnetworking

I am developing an application. In which it is required to upload more than 100 images on server. For which ima using AFNetworking here is my code `

```
AFHTTPClient *client= [AFHTTPClient clientWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://myserver/upload_video.php"]];
        NSDictionary* params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"saveMediaVideo", @"methodName",userID,@"user_id",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[imageArray count]],@"img_count",@"480.0000",@"img_height" , nil];

        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [client multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" path:@"http://myserver/upload_video.php" parameters:params constructingBodyWithBlock: ^(id <AFMultipartFormData>formData) {
            for (int i =0; i<[imageArray count]; i++) {
                NSData *imageToUpload = UIImageJPEGRepresentation([imageArray objectAtIndex:i], 1.0);
            [formData appendPartWithFileData: imageToUpload name:@"media[]" fileName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"temp_%d.jpg",i] mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];
            }
        }];
       AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];

        [operation setUploadProgressBlock:^(NSUInteger bytesWritten, long long totalBytesWritten, long long totalBytesExpectedToWrite) {
            NSLog(@"Sent %lld of %lld bytes", totalBytesWritten, totalBytesExpectedToWrite);
        }];
        [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
            NSString *response = [operation responseString];
            NSLog(@"response: [%@]",response);
           [self performSelector:@selector(killHUD) withObject:@"Processing..."];
            CustomAlertPopUp *alert = [[CustomAlertPopUp alloc]initWithHeaderText:@"Message" detailText:@"Spin uploaded on Server." buttonTitle:@"Ok" withTag:10 forTarget:self];
            [alert showView:self.view];
        } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
            [self performSelector:@selector(killHUD) withObject:@"Processing..."];
            if([operation.response statusCode] == 403){
                NSLog(@"Upload Failed");
                return;
            }
            NSLog(@"error: %@", [operation error]);
            CustomAlertPopUp *alert = [[CustomAlertPopUp alloc]initWithHeaderText:@"Error" detailText:@"Error from server, Please try again." buttonTitle:@"Ok" withTag:0 forTarget:self];
            [alert showView:self.view];
        }];
        [operation start];
```

`

in `NSLog` i can observe complete process,

```
2013-02-15 19:15:37.755 MyProject[5815:907] Sent 6856280 of 6871277 bytes
2013-02-15 19:15:37.757 MyProject[5815:907] Sent 6859176 of 6871277 bytes
2013-02-15 19:15:37.759 MyProject[5815:907] Sent 6862072 of 6871277 bytes
2013-02-15 19:15:37.760 MyProject[5815:907] Sent 6864968 of 6871277 bytes
2013-02-15 19:15:37.762 MyProject[5815:907] Sent 6867864 of 6871277 bytes
2013-02-15 19:15:37.780 MyProject[5815:907] Sent 6871277 of 6871277 bytes
```

it means the process complets. But at server side I can get only 10 images. Please guide me.. why this happening.

Comment: Yes I am using apache...

Comment: Oh.. never mind - its PHP settings, not apache... I'm typing out an answer now that might help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could very possibly be a server side issue. There are some settings for PHP that have the capacity to limit the amount of data that can be transferred in a single request.

The settings are as follows -

- [`upload_max_filesize`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-max-filesize)
- [`post_max_size`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size)

Both can be set in the [`php.ini` file.](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php). The location of the specific file can be found by runing `phpinfo()`.

Comment: Hey @Lix thanks for posting the reply. According to my server guy   All these settings have been done at server side.Do you want Any additional info to help me more on this issue.

Comment: I'm sure all the settings "have been done". Otherwise your server wouldn't be running at all! :) What values are those two settings at? Right now, your error message is saying that the script is no managing to upload more than +-6.5 megabytes... The settings might need to be changed depending on the files you are uploading.

Comment: at server side `max_file_uploads = 600
memory_limit = 200M ( most images are 12-15KB )
post_max_size = 200M`

Answer (score 0):

It was a server problem. I had a dedicated server with two `.ini` files the support guy changed the value of `max_file_uploads` to 500. and it worked.

Comment: Ahh... yes yes.. Having more than one `php.ini` file can get confusing :P Note that in my answer I mentioned that you can use `phpinfo()` to find out exactly which ini file is being loaded.